# Comparison for cycle class maps for de Rham and etale cohomology via p-adic Hodge theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, algebraic-cycles, p-adic-hodge-theory, derham-cohomology

Let $K$ be a p-adic local field, $X$ a smooth projective variety over $Spec(K)$, $CH^k(X)$ the Chow group of pure codimension $k$. Then there are cycle maps

$cl^X_{DR}:CH^k(X)\to H^{2k}_{DR}(X/K)$   and   $cl^X_{et}:CH^k(X)\to H^{2k}_{et}(X,\mathbb{Q}_p)$.

There is also a comparison morphism $\alpha$ which comes from p-adic Hodge theory:

$\alpha\colon B_{dR} \otimes_K H^*_{dR}(X/K) \cong B_{dR}\otimes_{\mathbb{Q}_p} H^*_{et}(X\times_K \overline{K},\mathbb{Q}_p).$

**Question:**

(1) Are these two cycle class maps related via the comparison morphism $\alpha$? This would be analogous to what happens in the complex case:[image] (Perhaps Fontaine's $t\in B_{dR}$ appears?)

(2) If (1) is too difficult, I would be interested in just the case where $X=Y\times Spec(K)$ where $Y$ is defined over a number field $E$ and $K$ is a $p$-adic completion of $E$.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a reason you wrote the first cycle class map having $Z^k(X)$ instead of $\operatorname{CH}^k(X)$ as its domain?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I'm not sure if we can replace $Z^k(X)$ with $CH^k(X)$.

Comment: You should look at Niziol's paper "On Uniqueness of p-adic period morphisms." In particular, she shows that comparison theorems are compatible with Chern classes.

Comment: @JesseSilliman: that paper looks a bit fancy. I feel that this shouldn't involve studying Chern classes on *higher* $K$-theory. My strategy would be similar, though: replace $\operatorname{CH}^*(X)$ by $K_0(X)$ (they agree after tensoring with $\mathbb Q$), and use the splitting principle to reduce to the case of $c_1(\mathscr L)$ for $\mathscr L$ a line bundle. For this case an actual argument is needed, though.

Comment: I think that one can deduce that $\alpha$ respects the cycle class maps up to a scalar purely from the functorial properties of the comparison isomorphism. For $X=\mathbb{P}^1$ the element $\alpha(1\otimes c_1^{dR}(O(1)))$ is stable under the Galois action.  Hence, $\alpha(1\otimes c_1^{dR}(O(1)))=t\otimes a\cdot c_1^{\'et}(O(1))$ for some $a\in\mathbb{Q}_p$. For any curve $C$ considering a finite cover $C\to\mathbb{P}^1$ we get that $\alpha$ is the multiplication by $at$ on the second cohomology of $C$.

Comment: Finally, for any line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on a smooth proper $X$ we can conclude that $\alpha(1\otimes c_1^{dR})(\mathcal{L})=t^{-1}\otimes a\cdot c_1^{\'et}(\mathcal{L})$ since the class of $\mathcal{L}$ in the Neron-Severi group modulo torsion is completely determined by the restriction of $\mathcal{L}$ to all curves. However, to compute $a$ it is necessary to look at the actual construction of the comparison isomorphism which you have in mind.

Comment: @SashaP  Yes, thanks, it's a good idea. Since I am also not familiar with the concrete construction, I would do this sometime later. And I guess that $a$ would be a rational number.

Comment: @Bonbon There certainly are proofs, for which compatibility with the cycle maps is built in by design, e.g. Niziol's proof using K-theory. But, a priori, different proofs might give different comparison isomorphism.

Comment: An alternative reference for this compatibility is the appendix of the survey paper "Semistable Conjecture of Fontaine--Janssen: a survey" by Takeshi Tsuji, which also gives a number of other useful compatibilities.

Comment: Also, one slightly subtle issue here is that there are several different definitions of "the" comparison isomorphism, and whether or not the comparison iso is compatible with Chern classes could potentially depend on this choice. Fortunately, Niziol shows that most of the standard definitions (including Tsuji's) agree with one another, making this often a non-issue. But if e.g. you want to use the comparison isomorphism coming from rigid geometry a la Scholze, then you can't just appeal to Niziol.